# eclipse dtp mysql delimiter statement broken.

Tags: mysql, eclipse, delimiter, eclipse-dtp

all. 
I'm trying to use the eclipse dtp to work on a mySQL DB. Here's the code that's giving an issue:

```
drop function if exists checkTypedness;

DELIMITER //

create function checkTypedness(nom varchar(255)) 
returns int
reads sql data
    begin
    declare hits int;
    set hits = 0;
    [.....]
end 
//
```

gives:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //

create function checkTypedness(nom varchar(255)) 
returns int
' at line 1

Elapsed Time:  0 hr, 0 min, 0 sec, 0 ms.

I was really hoping to not have to use phpmyadmin to build the database...
Cheers,
Charles.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. It seems that there is no solution, because:

1. Eclipse dtp doesn't recognize "delimiter" statements. (it's a command interpreted by the client not by the server)
2. you can set a delimiter string in the preferences for "sql editor", but that is valid only  for the "execute current text" command.
3. Eclipse always recognize "go" as a delimiter, but still it breaks statements at semicolons.

I think it's a bug.